# writing recursive function to compute no. of graphs

Tags: python, recursion, graph

I am trying to write a code in python, to calculate the maximum graphs sets by using this formula for n vertices: 
2**(n(n-1)/2) (i hope i wrote it correctly)

i am trying to do it in the lowest complexity/running time buy using % of 1000000007- is recursive the right way? or iterative?

I've read the Wikipedia article regarding exponential squaring- but couldn't make the leap from there to my problem :(

after some pen and pen and paper work I've discovered that in this case- n(n-1)/2 is always even - so i am removing the block that deals with odd n values.

This is the code a wrote so far for the recursion-
x for the base (2) and n for the number of vertices:

```
def graphs_num(x, n):
n = (n*n-n)/2
if n == 0:
    return 0
elif n == 1:
    return 1
else:
    y = graphs_num(x, n/2)
    return y*y
```

no results so far -can you assist please?

2nd edit: (i forgot the x in the last line)

here's @alec's code:

```
def count(n, total=1):
n = (n*n-1)/2
if n < 2:
    return total
total *= 2 ** (n - 1) % 1000000007
return count(x, n-1, total)
```

count(4)

now I am looking to have x already defined as 2- so the only input need by the function will be n

Comment: Kindly share the wikipedia link and a snippet of your code showing what you have attempted. The question needs clarification.

Comment: What did you try to write, this question might be too broad because we dont know how much you need and where you stuck,

Comment: hi- I've edited my question- now with code i wrote so far- please share your insights. I think i get the general idea of the recursion - i just don't understand how do i replace the n exponent- with the n(n-1)/2 desired exponent (yes..i am real noob)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely familiar with this problem but based on the formula you gave this will return the same result for n >= 0 (I assume you wouldn't have a negative number of vertices).

```
def count(n, total=1):
    if n < 2:
        return total
    total *= 2 ** (n - 1)
    return count(n-1, total)

>>> count(5)
1024
```

Edit (explanation):

Basically you will notice that the values increase by a factor of 2**n.

```
>>> [2 ** (n * (n-1) // 2) for n in range(1, 6)]
[1, 2, 8, 64, 1024]
```

This can be illustrated by the following:

```
f(1) = 1 = 2**0
f(2) = 2 = 2**1 * 2**0
f(3) = 8 = 2**2 * 2**1 * 2**0
...
```

And simplified to show how it might be used recursively:

```
f(1) = 1 = 2**0
f(2) = 2 = 2**1 * f(1)
f(3) = 8 = 2**2 * f(2)
...
```

By this point, it is easy to notice the relationship is `f(n) = 2**(n-1) * f(n-1)`. In the recursive function, the lines underneath the base case do exactly this:

```
total *= 2 ** (n - 1)
return count(n-1, total)
```

I multiple the total by `2**(n-1)`, and recurse to the next value for n, remembering to decrement by 1. The base case ensures we bottom out below 2, and returns the total.

Now if you want to change the base of the exponent and use a mod, it will behave accordingly.

```
def count(x, n, total=1):
    if n < 2:
        return total
    total *= x ** (n - 1) % 1000000007
    return count(x, n-1, total)

>>> count(2, 3)
8
>>> count(3, 3)
27
```

Comment: If you'd like an explanation, let me know. It wasn't too complicated.

Comment: yes please- i am trying to figure out how to it while using % as well, to reduce the running time- please see my code above in the edited question

Comment: Why are there two inputs? Is `x` to keep count?

Comment: **x** is the base and **n** is the exponent as in x**n (or x^n)- i'll revise it in the original question

Comment: Do you expect to change the base, or will it always be 2?

Comment: lets start with a base 2 only - I want to understand the basic case before moving forward

Comment: @omegasupreme I added an explanation. If it answers your question please approve the answer

Comment: okkkkkk...I think i'm _starting_ to get the idea :) - great explanation dude - ill run now to try and run it...(yes..run twice :) )

Comment: hi, i get an overflow error :OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large') for n=4. please see my code(tried to change it to base 2 only for now) `def count(n, ans=1):
    n = (n*n-1)/2
    if n < 2:
        return ans
    ans *= 2 ** (n - 1) % 1000000007
    return drawEdges(n-1, ans)

count(4)
` - what did i do wrong this time?

Comment: Remove `n = (n*n-1)/2`. There is no need to adjust the value of `n` other than decrementing by 1 with each recursive call. Just use the working example I provided.

Comment: i tried this code and assigned x=2 in the function itself and n=4 from input...and 1 came out instead of 64...

Comment: Whoops, forgot x in the last line. Try now

Comment: yep - you're right- its fixed. now- say I want this function to ask for only 1 argument - the exponent (n) and let x be already defined "inside" it- (as base 2) how would you implement that?

Comment: Dude... that's the first thing in my answer.

Comment: well, unfortunately- it **works** on my IDE - but fails when I try to submit it to my TA... probably something with their platform- I really appreciate your time man.